# How to convert Eclipse Android project into Android Studio Project without Eclipse export?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle

The general consensus on how to migrate my Android project to Gradle involves exporting my Eclipse project to Gradle to get some gradle.build file which is required to import the project as a Non-Android Studio project to Android Studio. I am unable to use Eclipse at the moment because it's not functioning properly, so how else might I convert the project and acquire a gradle.build file for the project?

Please explain exactly what a gradle.build file is and how it works? I really appreciate everything in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Tools Site http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects says the preferred migration technique is to import your existing Eclipse project directly into AS.

That's better than creating a build.gradle file in Eclipse because AS will construct the standard project structure.

(If you *need* a build.gradle file from Eclipse, I suggest reinstalling Eclipse from scratch. It's easier than repairing an installation.)

A build.gradle file uses a Groovy-based DSL to say how to build a project. It's more flexible than Ant, eg you can add Groovy code to control access to the signing keys for release builds. It's also more compact and readable than Ant.